# Why do we define the hypergeometric function of a matrix argument for symmetric matrices only?

Tags: special-functions, symmetric-functions, hypergeometric-functions

The hypergeometric function of a matrix argument has form
$$
{}_pF_q^{(\alpha)}(a_1, \ldots, a_p; b_1, \ldots, b_q;X) = 
\sum_{k=0}^\infty\sum_{\kappa\vdash k} c^{(\alpha)}_{a,b} J^{(\alpha)}_\kappa(X), 
$$
where $J^{(\alpha)}_\kappa(X)$ is a (normalized) Jack polynomial and we have  $J^{(\alpha)}_\kappa(X) = J^{(\alpha)}_\kappa(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ where the $x_i$ are the eigenvalues of $X$.

In all papers and textbooks I read about that, $X$ is supposed to be real symmetric or Hermitian. In particular the eigenvalues of $X$ are real. However the Jack polynomial makes sense for complex variables $x_1$, $\ldots$, $x_n$. Therefore I would like to know why we consider only symmetric or Hermitian matrices $X$ ?

For example the equality ${}_0F_0(X) = \exp\bigl(\textrm{tr}(X)\bigr)$ still holds true when $X$ has complex eigenvalues.

The equality $\sum_{\kappa \vdash k} Z_\kappa(x_1, \ldots, x_n) = {(\sum x_i)}^k$ still holds true for the zonal polynomials $Z_\kappa$ when the $x_i$ are complex.

Herz's relation 
$$
{}_1F_1(a; b; x_1, \ldots, x_n) = \exp(\sum x_i) {}_1F_1(b-a;b; -x_1, \ldots, -x_n) 
$$
is valid when the $x_i$ are complex.

Herz's other relation 
$$
{}_2F_1(a_1, a_2; b; X) = \det(I-X)^{-a_2}{}_2F_1\bigl(b-a_1, a_2, b, -X(I-X)^{-1}\bigr)
$$
is still valid when $X$ is not symmetric and has complex eigenvalues.

The motivation of my question is that I'm currently writing an R package for the evaluation of the hypergeometric functions of a matrix argument and I'm wondering whether I should prevent the user to use non-symmetric/Hermitian matrices. All the relations I tested are still valid when I drop the symmetry assumption.

Comment: I'm talking completely ignorantly here, but would there be problems with branch cuts, if we try to use (diagonalisable, say) matrices with complex eigenvalues?